# Picture in middle of arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I'm working in beamer and want to put a picture in the middle of an arrow like this:
[image]

Problem is, I want the picture in the foreground. I tried using layers, but I kinda think the layers get overwritten by the beamer class layers.

Next thing:

```
\draw [myarrow2] (A1) to (B1.north west);
\path (A1) -- (B1.north west) coordinate[midway] (r);
\node at (r) {\includegraphics[width=3em]{sensor.png}};
```

I tried to use the node definiton in the \draw too, but the result is the same.

Any option to make it work?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: MWE

```
\documentclass[17pt,t,table]{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./figs/}}
\RequirePackage{pgfpages}
\RequirePackage{tikz,tikzscale,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows,calc,fadings,shadows.blur,positioning,spy,arrows,decorations.text,decorations.markings,quotes,angles,babel,backgrounds}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}   %% some additional layers for demo
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Übersicht}
    \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth,T]
        \column{\textwidth}
%       \vspace*{-5em}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{myarrow2/.style={->, >=latex, shorten >=2pt,shorten <=.5em,line width=.6em,color=red}}
    \node[](A1) at (0,0) {};
\node[right =of A1](A2) {}; 
\draw [myarrow2] (A1) to (A2);
\path (A1) -- (A2) coordinate[midway] (r);
\node at (r) {\includegraphics[width=3em]{sensor.png}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it is almost impossible to help you, since you not provide complete small document, which will show your problem. consequently all yours definitions used in code snippet is unknown ..

see if the following solution works for you:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm, demo]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
 \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path [draw=teal, line width=4mm, -Triangle] 
    (0,0) to node {\includegraphics[width=3em, height=3em]{sensor.png}} +(5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

with adding option `pos=...` to the node you can shift node position to place where you estimate to be better than now (at default position: `pos=0.5`), for example

```
\path [draw=teal, line width=4mm, -Triangle] 
    (0,0) to node[pos=0.4] {\includegraphics[width=3em, height=3em]{sensor.png}}
```

gives:

[image]

**addendum:**
regarding your mwe in edited question:

your arrow is covered by picture in node. you have two choices: make image narrower or make arrow longer. for example:

```
\documentclass[17pt,t,table, demo]{beamer}
\graphicspath{{./figs/}}
\RequirePackage{pgfpages}
\RequirePackage{tikz,tikzscale,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, arrows,
                backgrounds,
                calc,
                decorations.text, decorations.markings,
                fadings,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                shadows.blur,shapes.arrows,
                spy,
                babel,}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}   %% some additional layers for demo
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Übersicht}
    \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth,T]
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth} 
your solution: 

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{myarrow2/.style={draw=red, -latex, line width=.6em,
                          shorten >=2pt, shorten <=.5em}
        }
\node   (A1) {};
\node[right=of A1] (A2) {};
\draw[myarrow2] (A1) to node {\includegraphics[width=3em] {sensor.png}} (A2);
% to see your arrow
\draw[myarrow2] (A1) to (A2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{column}

\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
suggested correction:    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 44mm,
myarrow2/.style={draw=red, -latex, line width=.6em}
                        ]
\node               (A1) {};
\node[right=of A1]  (A2) {};
\draw[myarrow2] (A1) to node[pos=0.4] {\includegraphics[width=3em] {sensor.png}} (A2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, I added your line in my mwe and the picture is there but the arrow is gone..

Comment: @FlorianTrautmann, because your arrow is too short and it is covered by picture in node. you have two choices: make image narrower or make arrow longer:

Comment: Thank you!!, I just realized using all those options.. for some reason the png itself was half transparent an everywhere you look at the picture, the background is white so you cant see it..

Comment: @FlorianTrautmann, if you like to cover arrow, than to node option  add`fill=white`. this requirement is not clear from question.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your MWE! From your picture I take that you want to have the arrow in the background and the arrow transparent. In order to do that, one has to use (and not only declare) the layers (but they come anyway with the background library, which you are loading) and use a transparency group in order to have no glitches in the arrow. Also the arrow is a bit short such that it gets covered by your image, I fixed that, too.

```
\documentclass[17pt,t,table]{beamer}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,backgrounds}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}   %% some additional layers for demo
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{\"Ubersicht}
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth,T]
\column{\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{myarrow2/.style={->, >=latex, shorten >=2pt,shorten <=.5em,line width=.6em,color=red}}
\node[](A1) at (0,0) {};
\node[right =5cm of A1](A2) {}; 
\begin{scope}[transparency group,opacity=0.5]
\draw[myarrow2] (A1) to coordinate[midway] (r) (A2) ;
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\node at (r) {\includegraphics[width=3em]{example-image-duck}};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

Without transparency group
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{myarrow2/.style={->, >=latex, shorten >=2pt,shorten <=.5em,line width=.6em,color=red}}
\node[](A1) at (0,0) {};
\node[right =5cm of A1](A2) {}; 
\draw[myarrow2,opacity=0.5] (A1) to coordinate[midway] (r) (A2) ;
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\node at (r) {\includegraphics[width=3em]{example-image-duck}};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Well, without transparency it is much easier.

```
\documentclass[17pt,t,table]{beamer}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{\"Ubersicht}
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth,T]
\column{\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{myarrow2/.style={->, >=latex, shorten >=2pt,shorten <=.5em,line width=.6em,color=red}}
\node[](A1) at (0,0) {};
\node[right =5cm of A1](A2) {}; 
\draw[myarrow2] (A1) to node[midway]{\includegraphics[width=3em]{example-image-duck}}
 (A2) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for the fast answer, I problem is, that I want the picture above the arrow without transparency.. So that the arrow is not visible behind the picture.. :)

Comment: @FlorianTrautmann I added a version without transparency.

Comment: Thank you!!, I just realized using all those options.. for some reason the png itself was half transparent an everywhere you look at the picture, the background is white so you cant see it..